# Polymer bower package

Tags: bower, polymer

Which `bower` package should I use for my project `polymer` or `polymer-polymer`?

I see that the `polymer` package is a shim around the `polymer-polymer` project.

The version lags behind quite heavily for `polymer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer team has not officially registered any packages with Bower registry. Instead, for now, we rely on using GitHub-based package notation.

For `Polymer` itself, this would be `Polymer/polymer`, e.g:

`bower install Polymer/polymer`

Fwiw, if you install any Polymer element via Bower, polymer and platform are installed automatically as well. E.g.

`bower install Polymer/core-toolbar`

Comment: Ah, so someone else has registered them. Thanks, Scott!

Comment: BTW, `polymer-polymer` currently points to `Polymer/polymer` if anyone hits this answer in the future.

Comment: We recommend using the git form (`bower install Polymer/polymer`) instead of the published packages (`bower install polymer-polymer` or `bower install polymer`) because the first is kept up to date more frequently. This goes for the elements too. There's still a lot of churn, so we haven't be diligent about published to the bower registry.